# Doesn't interrupt curl even if it returns "connection refused"

Tags: curl

i need to verify that my app started successfully .

```
curl --insecure --connect-timeout 5 --retry 10 --retry-delay 0 --max-time 500 https://127.0.0.1:9002
```

Command above works perfect, BUT i got error on start up
`(connection refused)`  because i have to wait sometime until tomcat turns on.

Does anybody know how to make CURL wait even if it gets `connection refused`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--retry-connrefused` flag.